# Conversion failed when converting nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone assist with the error I have below on this statement

```
SELECT 
    sh.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM,sh.shipment_id, sh.carrier,  
    sh.carrier_service,sh.carrier_type,sh.route,sh.customer_name,sh.total_lines,
    sh.total_weight,sh.total_volume,sh.SCHEDULED_SHIP_DATE AS SCHEDULED_SHIP_DATE,sh.total_qty,sh.trailing_sts,
    CASE 
       WHEN sh.CUSTOMER IN (46003204, 30321) 
          THEN 'CHUB' 
          ELSE '' 
    END AS CUSTOMER,
    (SELECT TOP 1 sd.customer_po 
     FROM shipment_detail sd 
     WHERE sd.internal_shipment_num = sh.internal_shipment_num
     ORDER BY sd.CUSTOMER_PO desc) as CUSTOMER_PO, 
    SH.REJECTION_NOTE
FROM
    shipment_detail sd
INNER JOIN 
    shipment_header_view sh ON sd.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = sh.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RYDI_orders RO ON SH.SHIPMENT_ID = RO.DELIVERY_id
WHERE 
    sh.leading_sts = 100 AND sh.trailing_sts = 100
GROUP BY
    sh.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM,sh.shipment_id, sh.carrier, 
    sh.carrier_service, sh.carrier_type, sh.customer,
    sh.route, sh.customer_name, sh.total_lines,
    sh.total_weight, sh.total_volume, sh.SCHEDULED_SHIP_DATE,
    sh.total_qty, sh.trailing_sts, SH.REJECTION_NOTE
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '50310H' to data type int.

Comment: So what is `H` in the value `50310H`? How can that be converted to an integer? Somewhere in that mess you posted you are either trying to convert that nvarchar value directly to an `int` using a cast/convert/etc **OR** you are doing an implicit conversion because you are comparing an integer to a nvarchar and the nvarchar values are being converted to int for the comparison. (*by mess I mean a dump of your query with no formatting, explanation, ddl, or anything else that would be of use*)

Comment: How else are we suppose to explain it to you???  The error is very very clear.  You tried to convert '50310H' to INT.  Even I don't know how it should turn out.

Comment: I like a wild stab in the dark every now and again. I'm betting sh.CUSTOMER isn't an int so your IN clause is tripping up.

Comment: What is it you are having trouble with?  The error message is obvious to say the least, somewhere in your query SQL Server is trying to convert the value '50310H' to an INT (which is a numeric datatype).  Can you edit your question by adding your DDL (create table statements)?

Answer (score 0):

My money is on the join or the where clause as your problem. I’ll offer debugging suggestions that may help since I can’t comment. 
To identify: If you have any idea what the 50310H is, if is it a shipment number or whatever, you can find it faster and compare the fields in the two tables. Another option is to just compare the table properties and see what the fields are. There might be two tables with values you’re trying to match, but one is int and one is nvarchar. 
To solve: The ultimate solution is to 
cast(whateverintfield as nvarchar) 
to stop it from arguing with you, once you’ve identified the offender. Good luck.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks everyone